# Check Lazy Load property has loaded in EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6, lazy-loading, dynamic-proxy

I'm using class properties by reflection in some operations so when using DynamicProxy instance it causes to load entire DB. (700+ classes are related with each other).

Is it possible to check if lazy load property loaded or not? Disabling dynamic proxy generation (`ProxyCreationEnabled = false`) is not usable in my case.

```
Customer oCustomer = context.get(1);

if(oCustomer.Location.HasLoaded)
   do smt..

public class Customer
{
    public decimal? Id {get; set;}
    public virtual CustomerLocation Location{get; set;}
}

public class CustomerLocation
{
    public decimal? Id {get; set;}
    public string Detail {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you are seeking for [DbReferenceEntry<TEntity, TProperty>.IsLoaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbReferenceEntry%602.IsLoaded);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) or [DbReferenceEntry.IsLoaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbReferenceEntry.IsLoaded);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property:

```
if (context.Entry(oCustomer).Reference(e => e.Location).IsLoaded)
```

or

```
if (context.Entry(oCustomer).Reference("Location").IsLoaded)
```

For collection type navigation properties, just use `.Collection` instead of `.Reference`.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Stoev, As a note for future, It's working when object state is not Detached.

Comment: Is there a way to check it without having the context (for example during validation of the entity)?

Comment: @bubi I wouldn't say absolutely impossible, but would be quite hard and has to dial with EF internals.